# In docker fails to do request to a python official docker image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I use dockerfile to build image and container. I haven't changed anything. But from yesterday, I cannot build it. My docker file is

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /src

COPY requirements.txt /src

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app/ /src/app

ENV PYTHONPATH=/src

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /src/app
```

I got below error.

```
ERROR: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: python:3.8-slim-buster: failed to copy: httpReadSeeker: failed open: failed to do request: Get "https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/cf/cf7d11e02afd21125c5378d971bc42cfed2b697d7c116b14eed0baad617839da/data?verify=1687069048-Wqw%2FLtaBudeh5Szh3s0QeRVV6q0%3D": dial tcp 104.18.123.25:443: i/o timeout
```

I don't know why this happens and I cannot find anything about this kind of error. Would you help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Could you check if you can download https://production.cloudflare.docker.com/registry-v2/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/cf/cf7d11e02afd21125c5378d971bc42cfed2b697d7c116b14eed0baad617839da/data?verify=1687069048-Wqw%2FLtaBudeh5Szh3s0QeRVV6q0%3D manually. Also check if you can other Python tags, 3.9 etc?

Comment: I can download it manually and I changed to another one 3.9-slim-buster. It has same error.

Comment: This seems like either a problem in your local networking environment (do you connect via some sort of proxy server?) or in Docker Hub's hosting; but not necessarily a programming problem _per se_ or something you could fix in code.

Comment: Where do you build this Dockerfile? Linux/Windows/Mac? Can you post the build command?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It is because of the network. I used the mirror to get the python image.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have logged in with another registry. It's trying to pull image from the registry that you mentioned while logging in.

```
docker login http://<YOUR-IP>:8080
```

Comment: But would that throw an "i/o timeout"?

Comment: Yes, In case registry doesn't exist.

Comment: I haven't logged any registry.

Comment: Either this image seems to have issue or maybe it's your docker configurations. You can try another docker image FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

Comment: The behavior you've described here doesn't happen. `docker pull python` and other names that don't mention a registry _always_ pulls from Docker Hub, even if you've `docker login` somewhere else.